# M 1.9.0.1 - SQL - Set manage stock 1 for all simple products

Tags: mysql, stock

I would like to update all my simple products in database by direct sql to set "manage stock" to 1 but don't know how to start.

Comment: Any specific reason behind using direct sql, you can easily achieve that by import of CSV file having 2 columns only!

Comment: Products where imported using third party service which left a lot of them without sku which seems to deny mass update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento basically  `mapped products  and its inventory`  to  `cataloginventory_stock_item` .

As  you want to update and then you need update the columns at **`manage_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock,is_in_stock.**

You can get simple product list from catalog_product_entity

`SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity where type_id='simple'`.

**Now You can fill your requirement by**

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item SET is_in_stock=1 , 
use_config_manage_stock =1,is_in_stock=1 where 
product_id in 
(SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity where type_id='simple')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are having products without SKUs then I suggest adding SKUs to the products first, or you are going to have a lot more critcal problems than just "Manage Stock" field. It's a complete recipe for an unstable system you got.

Coming back to question, it's a smallint field called "manage_stock" in cataloginventory_stock_item table in your DB if you don't have table prefix, otherwise 'PREFIX'_cataloginventory_stock_item. You might also want to set "use_config_manage_stock" while in there, so that you can control that for all products from a single location. Don't forget to re-index after this.